# Express - export multiple Router()s or a single Router()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to Express and programming in general.

If you follow [this book](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/web-development-mongodb-and-nodejs) you learn to create a single Router() which maps all the routes to all the controllers. You end up having:

```
controllers
    users.js
    (other controllers....)
routes
    routes.js
```

This router is then introduced to your app via a single call to `app.use(router)`.

---

However, if you generate your app via `express-generator`, it will generate a sample structure with multiple `Router()`s, which are then mounted to your app via multiple `app.use()` calls. For example:

```
app.use('/users', users) // mounts a Router()
app.use('/posts', posts) // mounts another Router()
```

> It seems that Express **prefers** to have a seperate Router mounted for each controller. Have I got it right?

In the `express-generator` example, callbacks are hard-wired into routes. Let's say you want to introduce controllers into your code.

You would end up having something like this?

```
controllers
    users
        routes.js
        callbacks.js
    [other controller]
        [its Router()].js
        [its callbacks].js
```

My questions is, which is the better way to go?

Is there some architectural concept I misunderstand? (Maybe I **should** be hard-wiring callbacks into routes when I'm usign multiple Routers?)

Thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-routers allows to separate your routes in modules. It avoids to have a big file with all routes. For example, if you take `app.use('/users', users)`, your *users.js* file will contain all routes associated to **users**.

Personally, I work on a project with *mongoose* (http://mongoosejs.com/) which use this architecture :

```
express/
    index.js <- Main file to configure express router with adding middlewares, etc.
    routes.js <- All your routes are required in this file 
    entities/
        users/
            users.model.js <- Model of the user
            users.controller.js <- Controller associated to the model. Any route call a function of the controller
            users.routes.js <- All routes for users
        projects/
            projects.model.js
            projects.controller.js
            projects.routes.js
```

With a multi-routers architecture, you will **gain scalability and readability**. And separation between callbacks and routes avoid to pollute your router with controllers code.